# Python is asking for me to indent, but when I do, the line doesn't work. What should I do?

Tags: python, indentation

I was wondering about a specific problem I was having while writing a program. The program is very simple. Ask for some info about the person with some input functions, and then compile the information into one paragraph, summarizing some info about the person.

Here's some code (I'll explain after):

```
def main():

userName = input("What's your name?")
userAge = input("How old are you?")
userNumber = input("What's your favorite number?")
userAnimal = input("What's your favorite animal?")

print("Hi, my name is" + userName + "and I'm" + userAge + ".")

print("My favorite number is" + userNumber + "and my favorite animal is" + userAnimal + ".")

main()
```

Python keeps asking me to indent the line "userName = input("What's your name?")", so I did that. But when I do that, the line just flat out disappears from when I run it.

Comment: You need to indent everything you want to run in `main()` — that's probably everything except, `main()`.

Comment: I'm guessing you want `main` to run all of those statements. You need to indent each line that you wish to be a part of `main`. I suggest you read up on [python functions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm)

Comment: Yes, always remember that Python does not use brackets to define blocks of code, completely unlike Java or C. Instead, Python forces you to use indentation.

Answer (score 3):

You meant to write :

```
def main():

    userName = input("What's your name?")
    userAge = input("How old are you?")
    userNumber = input("What's your favorite number?")
    userAnimal = input("What's your favorite animal?")

    print("Hi, my name is : " + userName + " and I'm " + userAge + ".")

    print("My favorite number is : " + userNumber + " and my favorite animal is " + userAnimal + ".")

main()
```

Comment: You should add the common `if __name__ == "__main__":` check around the call to [main](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html). I assume the OP is not familiar with that given he/she is new to Python.

Comment: I bet he's not about to import this as a module :)

Comment: Sure, I bet you are right for now, which hardly guarantees that will be right forever in any code base. It's a good habit to make.

Answer (score 0):

You have to indent the content of the main function.

```
def main():
    userName = input("What's your name?")
    userAge = input("How old are you?")
    userNumber = input("What's your favorite number?")
    userAnimal = input("What's your favorite animal?")

    print("Hi, my name is" + userName + "and I'm" + userAge + ".")

    print("My favorite number is" + userNumber + "and my favorite animal is" + userAnimal + ".")

main()
```

Comment: No worries. Happy to help here.